# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have this function that should do is to save in a field ( ' niu ' ) a sequence when the form is saved. This form is in the sale.order.line model.
[image]

```
niu = fields.Char(string="NIU", readonly=True)

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type == 'product' and not rec.niu:
                if vals.get('niu') == ' ':
                    vals[u'niu'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('sale.order.line')
                result = super(SaleOrder, self).create(vals)
                return result
```

But when I press the Save button, Odoo shows me the following error:
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'**

Why is this happening? What can I do?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Attribute Error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Comment: doesn't seems a duplicate to me: we don't know which problem the other post was referring to

Answer (score 2):

you don't need the `for rec in self` loop because you are into create. 
you don't have any access to the object field through `self`, which is empty at the moment. You need to use only `vals`.
you need to change the method decorators:

```
@api.model
@api.returns('self', lambda value:value.id)
def create(self, vals):
```

I really think you should have a read at Odoo [basics](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html), this is not the first problem you have that you could avoided reading them deeply...
Also, have a look at account_invoice.py into account module which shows plenty of v8 api